# Customer Register Page Validate min 1 Char to 10 Charcters - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, validation, form-validation, registration

I am trying to Change Validation in customer Registration page for first name and last name.

I know i can do this by setting `maxlimit` by `overriding` core template in theme folder.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml

But i dont seem this to be solid.

Any other Suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my Own Question.

Some of the suggestions I found

1. Add a Js **mixin** and extend the validation **rules.js**
2. In **customer_eav_attribute** table, modify **validate rules**
   column min and max length
3. Adding **class** to the input type `validate-length
   maximum-length-10 minimum-length-1`

Thanks